# Limit connected socket per computer/user in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How can I limit the number of connected socket per computer/user to Socket.IO server?

I know I can use session, but if the user tries to use multiple web browser then that would be useless.
IP address could also be used in this case, but if I use IP address then it would prevent other users behind the same router (same IP address) to connect to the server

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Why would this matter? You won't be able to stop someone malicious from spoofing browsers, IP addresses, etc. But if your goal is simply to throttle traffic, just set a limit per IP (say 5-10) and use the session to limit per-user. That should do : )

Answer (score 3):

**You can only limit connections by:**

a) IP, which you said you don't want 
b) Browser, since you can remember cookies (but if somebody opens multiple 'incognito' tabs with Chrome for example it can bypass this; also if they open another browser they can bypass this)

You cannot determine if a user is behind a router.

**My suggestion:**

Limit by both ip and browser: set a maximum number of connections for an ip and allow only one connection for the same browser.

Comment: "set a maximum number of connections for an ip and allow only one connection for the same browser." -- how? an example would be appreciated